# How can I prevent Safari from changing the styling?

Tags: css, safari

The first image is how the styling appears on Safari for a moment when the page renders, then it changes to the styling in the second picture.  I haven't had this issue before and I'm not sure how to prevent it.  Chrome is rendering properly.

The stack I am using is nextjs with Material-UI library if that makes a difference.

Any ideas?

[image: Correct]

[image: Incorrect]

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default withStyles(theme => {
    const colors = theme.palette.colors;

    return {
        hidden: {
            display: 'none'
        },
        title: {
            fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed',
            fontSize: 22,
            margin: '15px 0 20px 0'
        },
        subTitle: {
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: 300,
            color: '#aaaaaa',
            margin: '0 0 30px 0'
        },
        awardsCont: {
            maxWidth: 340,
            margin: '0px auto 48px auto'
        },
        awardCont: {
            width: 70,
            height: 95,
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            margin: 'auto'
        },
        awardSelected: {
            background: '#EBEBEB',
            borderRadius: 3
        },
        awardIcon: {
            height: 50,
            width: 'auto',
            transform: 'translate(-50%)',
            marginLeft: '50%'
        },
        awardText: {
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: 500,
            color: '#aaaaaa'
        },
        good: {},
        great: {
            color: '#fcc73f'
        },
        perfect: {
            color: '#a4aebc'
        },
        subtitleContainer: {
            paddingLeft: 6
        },
        subTitle2: {
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: 300,
            color: '#b9b9b9',
            // color: 'blue',
            marginBottom: 10,
            textAlign: 'center'
            // [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
            //  textAlign: 'left',
            //  paddingLeft: 6
            // }
        },
        tagsContainer: {
            [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
                width: '50vw',
                margin: '0 auto'
            },
            [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
                width: '80%',
                margin: '0 auto'
            },
            [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
                width: '90%',
                margin: '0 auto'
            }
        },
        // tagsCont: {
        //  width: '100vw',
        //  boxSizing: 'border-box',
        //  padding: 8
        // },

        subTitle2: {
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: 300,
            color: '#aaaaaa',
            marginTop: 40,
            marginBottom: 10
        },
        comment: {
            width: 'calc(100% - 32px)',
            height: 100,
            margin: '0 16px 20px 16px',
            padding: 8,
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontWeight: 300,
            fontSize: 16,
            color: '#A9A9A9',
            background: 'white',
            boxShadow: '0px 2px 6px rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.2)',
            borderRadius: 5,
            border: 'none',
            '&:focus': {
                outline: 'none',
                background: 'white',
                fontWeight: 300,
                color: '#A9A9A9'
            },
            '&:active': {
                outline: 'none',
                background: 'white',
                color: '#A9A9A9',
                fontWeight: 300
            },
            [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
                margin: 0,
                width: '100%'
            }
        },
        submitBtn: {
            width: 140,
            height: 45,
            margin: '0 10px 40px auto',
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontSize: 16,
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            boxShadow: '0px 4px 8px rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.1)',
            background: '#E0E0E0',
            borderRadius: 5,
            color: 'white',
            [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
                margin: '8px 0 0 auto'
            }
        },
        clickable: {
            background: '#FF9649',
            cursor: 'pointer'
        },
        //prev styling below
        groupNotSelected: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            margin: '0 10px',
            fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed',
            fontSize: '16px',
            fontWeight: '300',
            letterSpacing: '0.05em',
            color: '#AAAAAA'
        },
        purpose: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            margin: '0 10px',
            padding: '3px 10px',
            borderRadius: 5,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            letterSpacing: '0.05em',
            fontSize: '16px',
            backgroundColor: '#FFEAE4',
            color: '#D24207',
            cursor: 'pointer'
        },
        features: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            margin: '0 10px',
            padding: '3px 10px',
            borderRadius: 5,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            letterSpacing: '0.05em',
            fontSize: '16px',
            backgroundColor: '#FFEFDE',
            color: '#FF982A'
        },
        location: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            margin: '0 10px',
            padding: '3px 10px',
            borderRadius: 5,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            letterSpacing: '0.05em',
            fontSize: '16px',
            backgroundColor: '#FFF4D7',
            color: '#F4C95D'
        },
        body: {
            width: '98%',
            margin: '0 auto',
            [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
                width: '80%'
            },
            [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
                width: '60%'
            }
        },
        filterSelectionGroup: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            padding: '0 8px'
        },
        filter: {
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: 58,
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontWeight: '300'
        },
        // card: {
        //  boxSizing: 'border-box',
        //  paddingLeft: 20,
        //  cursor: 'pointer',
        //  display: 'flex',
        //  alignItems: 'center',
        //  justifyContent: 'left',
        //  height: 58,
        //  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        //  fontWeight: 300,
        //  fontSize: '16px',
        //  borderRadius: 5,
        //  backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        //  color: '#AAAAAA',
        //  boxShadow: '0px 3px 4px rgba(105, 51, 12, 0.3);',
        //  [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
        //      borderRadius: 15,
        //      height: 110,
        //      fontSize: 18
        //  }
        // },
        card: {
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            margin: 6,
            paddingLeft: 20,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'left',
            height: 58,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontWeight: 300,
            fontSize: '16px',
            borderRadius: 5,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            color: '#AAAAAA',
            boxShadow: '0px 3px 4px rgba(105, 51, 12, 0.3);'
        },
        purposeSelected: {
            color: '#D24207 !Important',
            backgroundColor: '#FFEAE4',
            zIndex: 20,

            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            margin: 6,
            paddingLeft: 20,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'left',
            height: 58,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontWeight: 300,
            fontSize: '16px',
            borderRadius: 5,
            boxShadow: '0px 3px 4px rgba(105, 51, 12, 0.3);'
        },
        featureSelected: {
            color: '#FF982A !Important',
            backgroundColor: '#FFEFDE',
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            margin: 6,
            paddingLeft: 20,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'left',
            height: 58,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontWeight: 300,
            fontSize: '16px',
            borderRadius: 5,
            boxShadow: '0px 3px 4px rgba(105, 51, 12, 0.3);'
        },
        locationSelected: {
            color: '#F4C95D !Important',
            backgroundColor: '#FFF4D7',
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            margin: 6,
            paddingLeft: 20,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'left',
            height: 58,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontWeight: 300,
            fontSize: '16px',
            borderRadius: 5,
            boxShadow: '0px 3px 4px rgba(105, 51, 12, 0.3);'
        },
        firstSubTitle: {
            margin: 0,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto condensed',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '14px',
            color: '#AAAAAA',
            textAlign: 'left'
        },

        icon: {
            justifySelf: 'start',
            marginRight: 12
        },
        submit: {
            position: 'fixed',
            bottom: 70,
            margin: '0 auto',
            [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
                position: 'relative',
                marginTop: 90,
                marginBottom: -45
            }
        },
        submitButtonIcon: {
            width: 'auto',
            height: 15,
            margin: 'auto 0 auto 5px'
        },
        buttonsContainer: {
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            margin: '0 auto'
        },

        locationContainer: {
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            marginLeft: -20,
            [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
                maxWidth: '80%',
                padding: 0
            },
            [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
                maxWidth: '100%',
                padding: 0
            }
        },

        input: {
            boxShadow: '0px 4px 8px rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.1);',
            border: 'none',
            width: '100%',
            height: 50,
            marginLeft: -25,
            marginRight: -35,
            borderRadius: 5,
            color: '#AAAAAA',
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: 300,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            textAlign: 'center'
        },
        locationIcon: {
            zIndex: 1,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 35,
            color: '#F4C95D',
            margin: 'auto',
            marginRight: -20
        },
        arrowIcon: {
            color: '#F4C95D'
        },
        blueLineSelected: {
            color: '#3C91E6  !Important',
            backgroundColor: '#ECF5FF !Important'
        },
        redLineSelected: {
            color: '#EA2B1F !Important',
            backgroundColor: '#F9E3E2  !Important'
        },
        brownLineSelected: {
            color: '#61210F !Important',
            backgroundColor: '#F9EBE7 !Important'
        },
        pinkLineSelected: {
            color: '#CA2E55 !Important',
            backgroundColor: '#FCF2F5 !Important'
        },
        greenLineSelected: {
            color: '#00A878 !Important',
            backgroundColor: '#EEFFFA !Important'
        },
        orangeLineSelected: {
            color: '#FF6201 !Important',
            backgroundColor: '#FFF6F0 !Important'
        },
        trainContainer: {
            borderRadius: 5,
            [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
                borderRadius: 15
            }
        },
        subContainer: {
            zIndex: 1,
            height: 'auto',
            background: 'none'
        },
        brownLineContainer: {
            marginBottom: 50
        },
        subTag: {
            height: 10,
            padding: 10,
            margin: 8,
            background: 'white',
            boxShadow: '0px 3px 4px rgba(105, 51, 12, 0.3);',
            borderRadius: 5,
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontWeight: '300',
            fontSize: 16,
            color: '#AAAAAA'
        },
        successMessage: {
            // position: 'absolute',
            // top: 0,
            width: '100%',
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            padding: '10px 30px',
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: 300,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            lineHeight: '150%',
            color: '#4a8a4a',
            background: '#ccebc9'
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a classname called twice.  It wasn't breaking anything in a Chrome browser but it was in a Safari browser.  Once I removed the second class variable the styling worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

When consider this rendering issue, it seems like a style overriding issue. I guess you have used material `.container` class for html layout and after that you have overided that styles in `.container` class by changing it's default values. Webpage shows it's original styles values at initial paint and it takes few seconds to override that default styles by yours. This may be the reason for your layout change over the time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I am reading your comment correctly you believe it is displaying the MUI (material-UI) styling first, then processing my styling which causes that change?

Actually, the opposite of what you said is happening.  It is flashing my additional styles correctly, but then it removes a good portion of my styling but not all of it. 

I'm very stumped by this issue

Comment: @Ryan Yes, That is what I explain in my answer. Could you provide me your additional styles sheet via code snippet or live link?

Comment: I attached the jss style sheet if that helps.  I've tried commenting out sections of it to find the source of the issue but I could not.  MUI (material-ui) is working on most other pages for safari, not this one though.